# How to call a function on beforeclose event in bpopup?

Tags: jquery, bpopup

I want to  call a function before closing the bpopup. I have used following code:

```
$('#casepromptPopup').bPopup({
    escClose: false,
    closeClass: 'b-close',
    modalClose: false,
    onClose: function() {                         
        confirm("Are you sure you wish to quit and grade your performance?");
```

I want to show the confirm message before popup close. But `onClose` method fires after the popup close.

Comment: onClose is working as intended . Its fired after popup closed. For your purpose you can add a button in popup div and use confirm message on that .

Comment: I want to show the confirm message when user click on the close button and before popup close

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I'm not a fan of plugin modifications, it seems that there's no other way to achieve this.

Modify the [bpopup.js](https://github.com/dinbror/bpopup/blob/master/jquery.bpopup.js):

- **1.** Find `function close()` and add `if(o.confirmClose()){` :

  ```
  function close() {
      if(o.confirmClose()){
          // rest of the original function
      }
  }
  ```
- **2.** Find `$.fn.bPopup.defaults = {` (at the bottom) and add:

  ```
  confirmClose: function(){return true;}
  ```

Now you can add confirmation into your bpopup options:

```
$('#casepromptPopup').bPopup({
    escClose     : false,
    closeClass   : 'b-close',
    confirmClose : function(){                         
        return confirm("Are you sure you wish to quit and grade your performance?");
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/ntmrv5gm/)**